# grepで$記号を用いた行末指定が使えない

Tags: macos, bash, grep

**前提・実現したいこと**
macOSでbashでの正規表現の学習をしています。
grepで$記号を用いた行末指定をしようとしたのですが検索パターンが認識されません。

**発生している問題**
指定したzen.txtファイルにはidea.という文字列が含まれている行があるにも関わらず$を加えると認識されません。

```
name-no-MacBook-Pro:Desktop name$ grep idea.$ zen.txt
name-no-MacBook-Pro:Desktop name$
```

**該当のソースコード**
macOS bash

```
name-no-MacBook-Pro:~ name$ export GREP_OPTIONS='--color=always'
name-no-MacBook-Pro:~ name$ cd Desktop
name-no-MacBook-Pro:Desktop name$ grep idea.$ zen.txt
name-no-MacBook-Pro:Desktop name$
```

**試したこと**

```
name-no-MacBook-Pro:Desktop name$ grep idea. zen.txt
If the implementation is hard to explain, it's a bad idea.\
If the implementation is easy to explain, it may be a good idea.\
Namespaces are one honking great idea -- let's do more of those!}
```

**補足情報（FW/ツールのバージョンなど）**
ターミナル　バージョン2.9.5(421.2)

```
name-no-MacBook-Pro:Desktop name$ cat zen.txt
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg932\cocoartf1671\cocoasubrtf600
{\fonttbl\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Menlo-Regular;}
{\colortbl;\red255\green255\blue255;\red0\green0\blue0;}
{\*\expandedcolortbl;;\csgray\c0;}
\paperw11900\paperh16840\margl1440\margr1440\vieww10800\viewh8400\viewkind0
\pard\tx560\tx1120\tx1680\tx2240\tx2800\tx3360\tx3920\tx4480\tx5040\tx5600\tx6160\tx6720\pardirnatural\partightenfactor0

\f0\fs22 \cf2 \CocoaLigature0 The Zen of Python, by Tim Peters\
\
Beautiful is better than ugly.\
Explicit is better than implicit.\
Simple is better than complex.\
Complex is better than complicated.\
Flat is better than nested.\
Sparse is better than dense.\
Readability counts.\
Special cases aren't special enough to break the rules.\
Although practicality beats purity.\
Errors should never pass silently.\
Unless explicitly silenced.\
In the face of ambiguity, refuse the temptation to guess.\
There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.\
Although that way may not be obvious at first unless you're Dutch.\
Now is better than never.\
Although never is often better than *right* now.\
If the implementation is hard to explain, it's a bad idea.\
If the implementation is easy to explain, it may be a good idea.\
Namespaces are one honking great idea -- let's do more of those!\
}
```

Comment: 「試したこと」の grep コマンドの結果では `... idea.\ `  となっていて、行末にバックスラッシュが付いている様に見えます。これは写し間違いでしょうか？

Comment: 写し間違いではなく、正しくは行末にバックスラッシュがついています。zen.txtファイルにの中身についてですがテキストファイルを開いてコピーしただけのものになります。こちらのミスでした、すいません。

Comment: バックスラッシュを加えて、シングルクォートでくくって実行してみましたがやはりうまくいきません。以下コードの実行結果です。 ``` 
name-no-MacBook-Pro:Desktop name$ grep 'idea.\$' zen.txt 
name-no-MacBook-Pro:Desktop name$ 
```

Comment: `grep 'idea\.\\$' zen.txt` を試してみて下さい。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/211580

Comment: ありがとうございます。意図通り動きました。

Answer (score 3):

パターンをシングルクォートでくくってみてください。

```
grep 'idea.$' zen.txt
```

裸の`$`などはシェルによって解釈されてしまうので、そういった場合にクォートでくくります。

---

(追記)
行末に`\`が含まれるのであれば、以下の通りエスケープして試してください。

```
grep 'idea.\\$' zen.txt
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
他の回答者の方にご指摘していただいたバックスラッシュも加えて、シングルクォートでくくって実行してみましたがやはりうまくいきません。以下コードの実行結果です。
```
name-no-MacBook-Pro:Desktop name$ grep 'idea.\$' zen.txt
name-no-MacBook-Pro:Desktop name$
```

Comment: バックスラッシュをバックスラッシュでエスケープしてないようです。grep 'idea.\$' zen.txtではなくgrep 'idea.\\$' zen.txtにすれば意図通り動くと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます。意図通り動きました。